# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with php inside js

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code inside php tag which itself is inside a script tag. Why does it give me that error?

```
print("document.getElementById(\"userComment\").innerHTML=\"
              <div style=\"background:url('assets/images/userImages/{$row4['image']}') no-repeat; width: 3em; height: 3em; background-position: center; background-size: 210%; border-radius: 50%;\">
              </div>\";");
```

Comment: Do you really have a line break after `innerHTML=\"`? JavaScript doesn't allow line breaks inside strings.

Comment: I don't, sorry for the poor formation here on stack overflow; was just trying to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting messed up by quoting problems. This would be a good place to use a here-string, so you don't need to worry about PHP quotes.

And in the JavaScript, use a template literal rather than a double-quoted string. This will allow you to have newlines in the string, and also avoid the problem of nested double quotes.

```
echo <<<EOS
document.getElementById("userComment").innerHTML=`
    <div style="background:url('assets/images/userImages/{$row4['image']}') no-repeat; width: 3em; height: 3em; background-position: center; background-size: 210%; border-radius: 50%;">
    </div>`;
EOS ;
```

Or get out of PHP mode into literal output:

```
?>
document.getElementById("userComment").innerHTML=`
    <div style="background:url('assets/images/userImages/<?php echo $row4['image']; ?>') no-repeat; width: 3em; height: 3em; background-position: center; background-size: 210%; border-radius: 50%;">
    </div>`;
<?php
```